# Make autocomplete work after a fullstop

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have this piece of code that works pretty well.Currently every new word to be autosearched requires a space before its start.I want autosearch to work even after the fullstop(sentence completion).Any help is appreciated :)

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jc92619/3yTPJ/3/

```
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];

  var faux = $("#faux");
  var arrayused;
  var calcfaux;
  var retresult;
  var checkspace;
  var contents = $('#tags')[0];
  var carpos;
  var fauxpos;
  var tier;
  var startss;
  var endss;

  function getCaret(el) {
    if (el.selectionStart) {
      return el.selectionStart;
    } else if (document.selection) {
      el.focus();

      var r = document.selection.createRange();
      if (r == null) {
        return 0;
      }

      var re = el.createTextRange(),
        rc = re.duplicate();
      re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
      rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re);

      return rc.text.length;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  function split(val) {
    return val.split(/ \s*/);
  }

  function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
  }
  $("#tags")
    .on("keydown", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    })
    .click(function(event) {
      carpos = getCaret(contents);
      fauxpos = faux.text().length;
      if (carpos < fauxpos) {
        tier = "close";
        $(this).autocomplete("close");
        startss = this.selectionStart;
        endss = this.selectionEnd;
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/ *$/, ''));
        this.setSelectionRange(startss, endss);
      } else {
        tier = "open";
      }

    })
    .on("keyup", function(event) {
      calcfaux = faux.text($(this).val());
      fauxpos = faux.text().length;
      if (/ $/.test(faux.text()) || tier === "close") {
        checkspace = "space";
      } else {
        checkspace = "nospace";
      }


      if (fauxpos <= 1) {
        tier = "open";
      }
      carpos = getCaret(contents);
      if (carpos < fauxpos) {
        tier = "close";
        $(this).autocomplete("close");
        startss = this.selectionStart;
        endss = this.selectionEnd;
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/ *$/, ''));
        this.setSelectionRange(startss, endss);
      } else {
        tier = "open";
      }
    })
    //mouse caret position dropdown
    .autocomplete({
      minLength: 1,
      search: function(event, ui) {
        var input = $(event.target);
        // custom minLength
        if (checkspace === "space") {
          input.autocomplete("close");
          return false;
        }
      },
      source: function(request, response) {

        var term = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(extractLast(
            request.term))
          // Create two regular expressions, one to find suggestions starting with the user's input:
          ,
          startsWithMatcher = new RegExp("^" + term, "i"),
          startsWith = $.grep(availableTags, function(value) {
            return startsWithMatcher.test(value.label || value.value ||
              value);
          })
          // ... And another to find suggestions that just contain the user's input:
          ,
          containsMatcher = new RegExp(term, "i"),
          contains = $.grep(availableTags, function(value) {
            return $.inArray(value, startsWith) < 0 &&
              containsMatcher.test(value.label || value.value ||
                value);
          });

        // Supply the widget with an array containing the suggestions that start with the user's input,
        // followed by those that just contain the user's input.
        response(startsWith.concat(contains));
      },
      open: function(event, ui) {
        var input = $(event.target),
          widget = input.autocomplete("widget"),
          style = $.extend(input.css([
            "font",
            "border-left",
            "padding-left"
          ]), {
            position: "absolute",
            visibility: "hidden",
            "padding-right": 0,
            "border-right": 0,
            "white-space": "pre"
          }),
          div = $("<div/>"),
          pos = {
            my: "left top",
            collision: "none"
          },
          offset = -7; // magic number to align the first letter
        // in the text field with the first letter
        // of suggestions
        // depends on how you style the autocomplete box

        widget.css("width", "");

        div
          .text(input.val().replace(/\S*$/, ""))
          .css(style)
          .insertAfter(input);
        offset = Math.min(
          Math.max(offset + div.width(), 0),
          input.width() - widget.width()
        );
        div.remove();

        pos.at = "left+" + offset + " bottom";
        input.autocomplete("option", "position", pos);

        widget.position($.extend({
          of: input
        }, pos));
      },
      focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {
        var terms = split(this.value);
        startss = this.selectionStart;
        endss = this.selectionEnd;
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push(ui.item.value);
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push("");
        this.setSelectionRange(startss, endss);
        this.value = terms.join(" ");
        calcfaux = faux.text($(this).val());
        if (/ $/.test(faux.text())) {
          checkspace = "space";
        } else {
          checkspace = "nospace";
        }
        carpos = getCaret(contents);
        fauxpos = faux.text().length;
        return false;
      }
    });
```